# What is the replacement for getFromLocationName() for IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, marker

I have implemented google map on IOS, now i want to locate marker on some company brand name, before i have experience of implementing in Android.
In Android getFromLocationName() to get the address info like lat, long from geocoder but I am not getting any in build function like this in IOS?

any help?

Comment: where u struck , can you show ur tried code

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH4-SW5  I am using this url for forward geocoding, where i want to sent address and get the marker ploted on it, but getting error  Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=8 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 8.)"

Comment: [Utilities forwardGeocode:addressString
            completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                if (error)
                    NSLog(@"Geocode error: %@", error);
                else if (placemarks.count > 0)
                {
                    
                    NSArray*arr=placemarks;
//                    addrPlacemark = [placemarks firstObject];
//                    NSLog(@"fwd geocode: %f %f",
//                          addrPlacemark.location.coordinate.latitude,
This is type of code

Answer (score 1):

i think its giving you error because, geocoder is not able to find the location.

check this code ,

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:@"Palolem Beach, Goa, India" completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
    if (!error) {

        for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark in placemarks)
        {
            NSLog(@"place--%@", [aPlacemark locality]);
            NSLog(@"lat--%f\nlong--%f",aPlacemark.location.coordinate.latitude,aPlacemark.location.coordinate.longitude);
        }
    }
    else{

        NSLog(@"error--%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];
```

Comment: Let me try this, but KFC,pune should be correct address, otherwise how i locate it?

Comment: pardon can you elobrate,please

Comment: I want to locate KFC,pune

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/maps/search/KFC,pune/@18.5839379,73.7060018,12z/data=!3m1!4b1?hl=en      , address may not be wrong , because google map locating it

Comment: if you put `KFC,pune` like you get multiple locations, in here you need to add your address also

Comment: that will be ok if i will get multiple location , but i use "KFC,pune" i am getting error, if i type dominos,pune that return me result

Comment: [self forwardGeocode:@"KFC,pune,India"]; Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=8 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 8.)"